# path expected for join JPA Hibernate MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, hibernate, jpa

I'm using composite PK in my app with 2 tables and one joining table.

I wrote this query for function:

```
   @Repository
public interface HospitalDoctorDao extends JpaRepository<HospitalDoctor, Integer>{

@Query("select hd from HospitalDoctor hd join hospital on hd.hospital_id=hospital.id join doctor on hd.doctor_id = doctor.id where hospital_id = ?1  and doctor_id = ?1")
HospitalDoctor findByHospitalIdAndDoctorId(int hospital_id, int doctor_id);
}
```

and I am getting error Path expected for file! In MySQL everything is working. How Hibernate works in this case? How I should write this query? Here is my @Entity of join table:

```
    @Entity
@Table(name = "hospital_doctor")
public class HospitalDoctor {

    @Embeddable
    static class HosdocPK implements Serializable {
        private int hospitalId;
        private int doctorId;
    }

    @EmbeddedId
    @JsonBackReference
    public HosdocPK hosdocPK;



    @JsonManagedReference
    @MapsId("DoctorId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "doctorId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Doctor doctor;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @MapsId("HospitalId")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "hospitalId", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Hospital hospital;



    @Column(name = "Id")
    private int id;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date contract_start_date;
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date contract_end_date;
    private String position;
    private String supervisor;
    private boolean part_time;


    Getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query is incorrect.

Try:

```
select hd from HospitalDoctor hd where hd.hospital.id = ?1 and hd.doctor.id = ?2
```

Comment: Thanks! That work's but now I'm getting a Internal Server Error Optional int parameter 'doctor_id' is present but cannot be translated into a null value due to being declared as a primitive type. Consider declaring it as object wrapper for the corresponding primitive type. I am using Get method to this with " /api/hospitaldoctors/{hospital_id}/{doctor_id}" URL. How I should declare it as a object wrapper?

Comment: Yes, in your @PathVariable(if you are using Spring) define it like as Integer.